# Ошибка создания экземпляра класса сервлета [servlet.jab]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

у меня есть этот сервлет jab.java

```
  package servlet;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class jab extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws SecurityException, IOException, SecurityException{
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer;

        String f, nGrad, tGrad;
        double vGrad = 0;

        f = req.getParameter("fun");
        tGrad = req.getParameter("trig");
        nGrad = req.getParameter("num");

        writer = resp.getWriter();

        try {
            vGrad = Double.parseDouble(nGrad);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.err.println("err");
        }

        if(tGrad.equals("grad")){
            vGrad = Math.toRadians(vGrad);
        }

        switch (f) {
            case ("tg"):
            {
                vGrad = Math.tan(vGrad);
            }
            case ("sin"):
            {
                vGrad = Math.sin(vGrad);
            }
            case ("cos"):
            {
                vGrad = Math.cos(vGrad);
            }
        }

        writer.println("<p>value "+vGrad+"</p>");
    }
}
```

Который зарегистрирован как показано ниже в web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name> Jab </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> servlet.jab </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name> Jab </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern> /welcome </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Я получила ошибку при запуске веб-приложения:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Ошибка создания экземпляра класса сервлета [servlet.jab]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet.jab
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: я не спец, но позоже вам тут не надо указывать пекет `<servlet-class> servlet.jab </servlet-class>` -> `<servlet-class> jab </servlet-class>`

Comment: @tym32167 без пакета не находит класс

Comment: судя по ошибке, он его и с пакетом не находит

Comment: [оно](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-exception-spring-mvc-tomcat-and-404-error/) ?

Comment: @tym32167 не могу найти Properties d intellij idea.....